# Is it possible to automate the deployment of .rdl files to PowerBI, using Devops tools like Bamboo?

Tags: automation, powerbi, bitbucket, devops, bamboo

I have to constantly manually download .rdl files from my git repository and then upload them manually to PowerBI. I don't have much knowledge of PowerBI but I'm only responsible for these deployments. This I feel is a time consuming process and I feel this could be done by automating the deployment process through a DevOps pipeline in Bamboo or similar. I research a bit but couldn't find anything relevant on this topic.

If anyone could help me out by suggesting potential solutions to the problem that would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: You can do that using the [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/post-import-in-group).

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Could you elaborate on that? How to go about implementing a CICD pipeline using it?